# GTA 5, story mode - The Long Stretch nor Friend Request is showing up

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, ps4

I'm new to this game and so far I have completed Prologue, Franklin and Lamar, Repossession, Complications, Father Son, Chop (I think. I dropped everyone off at least), Marriage Counseling and Daddy’s Little Girl. From there, nothing is showing up. Spent days towing cars, flew some planes, played tennis, won triathlons, beat up some bike thieves, shot some aliens, called everyone, visited the shrink, helped the paparazzi kid, walked the dog but nothing.

The only playable characters are Michael and Franklin.

Is there a specific trigger to progress in the game from here?

Answer (score 1):

The trigger for Friend Request was Lesters actual front door, not his driveway. Similar story for The Long Stretch was Franklins door, not just close to it.